# In .md file: How to add background color to a text? or Put text in a colored box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add some background color to a text like below in a .md file. How can I do that?

> Like this is some randomw text for you. Like this is some randomw
>   text for you. Like this is some randomw text for you.Like this is some
>   randomw text for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe backticks produce an inline `<code>` (or `<pre>` maybe) tag when compiled. Then just style that particular tag.